# Как передать в функцию массив, который хранится в обьекте

Tags: c++

У меня в объекте класса хранится инициализированный массив.
Теперь нужно в отдельной функции сделать манипуляции с этим массивом, но мне его нужно передать как параметр в функцию. Как мне передать массив в функцию, если этот массив хранится в объекте?

Comment: если это ф-ция объекта - передавать и не надо, массив в объекте...

Comment: если переменная приватная, а функция - отдельностоящая,  тогда нужно как то сделать "переходник".

Comment: Приведите код, пожалуйста в качестве примера.

Answer (score 3):

Простой ответ, например вот так:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        m_array = {1,2,3,4,5};
    }

    const std::vector<int>& get_array() const
    {
        return m_array;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> m_array;
};

void some_global_func(const std::vector<int>& _vec)
{
    for (auto& it : _vec)
        std::cout << it << " ";
}

int main()
{
    MyClass my;

    some_global_func(my.get_array());

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Вам надо немного уточнить про то, какой именно массив у вас хранится. Например, в примере массив динамический (обёрнутый в std::vector), а у вас может быть статический. Передавать нужно будет через указатель, так как нет такого понятия "передать статический массив в функцию".

Так или иначе принцип тот же, вы должны объявить и определить функцию-член класса, которая предоставляет доступ к массиву (например, возвращает на него указатель/ссылку/копию), так вы не будете нарушать принципы инкапсуляции. Можно сам массив сделать public, но это плохой стиль и рано или поздно приведёт к ошибкам.

А вообще, существует такой принцип проектирования GRASP, как "информационный эксперт" (information expert), который гласит, что данные по возможности должны обрабатываться там же, где хранятся. Подумайте, правильно ли вы всё спроектировали.

Comment: по сути массив может выглядеть как указатель. типо `int* a = new int[10];` и тогда передавать в функцию нужно иначе.

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов Разумеется! Но автор не уточнил, что у него за массив. В этом случае нужно передавать или указатель + размер, или начало + конец. Однако для динамических массивов всё-таки лучше использовать STL. Если уж совсем никак, то хотя бы вместо сырых указателей (raw pointer) использовать умные (smart pointers)